# Hook functions class in offset (from .exe in a .dll)

Tags: c++, class, hook

I have a **.exe** application and I need to create some customizations to this executable, so I need to hook a dll in it for the changes to be loaded. Until then, everyone knows.

**The scenario is this:**
Hook(0xOffset, &myClass::myFunc);

There is a class in .exe that I need to rewrite completely and I've done that in my dll, but I'm having trouble with the hook of the functions of class, they aren't static. I've read many topics and I could not implement it with any method presented. In some cases, the compiler will not accept, in others cases has accepted but the .exe could not find the actual address of the function.

A friend gave me a solution, but it is a little confusing to understand how I can call the function there and from what I saw would be very big in my source code and many *loops*, so to speak.

Could help me?

Comment: You don't really need a hook, you just need a callback function. Or a mechanism for *dynamically* calling a function from a DLL. Are you programming in Windows? This is very likely to be an operating system-specific mechanism. For example, in Windows, there is `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` for dynamically invoking functions.

Comment: Yes, windows. I need only the functions of my class to be called in place of the original class functions. If that's what you're also thinking, which suggests me to do? An example?

Answer (score 0):

Member functions are indeed far more complex. You have to deal with normal inheritance, multiple inheritance, and virtual inheritance; with direct calls and virtual calls. Possibly the worst is dealing with member function pointers, which are entirely unlike normal function pointers.

As a result, many solutions deal only with the easy cases. It's perfectly normal that a solution capable of dealing with all edge cases takes a lot of code.